# Ruby on Rails - Categories as Hashes or Database Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, categories

I have a general question about whether people think you should use a database table or constants hashes/arrays for categories.  I'm torn on which way to go.  Thoughts?

Comment: Is "categories" in this instance a small, immutable set of data or will that data grow, shrink, and change over time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are 100% sure you won't ever change the categories, you could go for a custom model with the Object superclass (no DB-table and no ActiveRecord).

If you ever would change a category or add any you want a database. This is because your models won't get reloaded after a change in production mode.

I still recommend a database anyway because of at least the following:

1. See MattC's comment.
2. You can use ActiveRecord relationships (has_many and belongs_to). This is hard to do without ActiveRecord.
3. The performance decrese is not significant. It might slow down 0.2ms at most.

Comment: I can't tell you how many times I've been "100% sure" of something and had it change on me.

Comment: I completely agree, Matt. This is serious business.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think this makes perfect sense and I'll stick with the database.  I have it there now but was second guessing my decision for some of the categories

Answer (score 2):

Having them stored in the database (and used as a model) make it more flexible for the future.  Adding/Removing new categories could be done without a redeploy of the app, whereas having them as hard-coded constant values would.

But with that said, it all depends on your specific needs.  If you know for a fact that the categories will never change, constants might be better since that would mean less database hits.